# Does Google's GSON use constructors?

Tags: java, json, gson

I was wondering something when working on our project. Does the GSON API from Google use the constructors from the JSON's you want to deserialize? So for example:

I've got a JSON String which I want to convert to an Employee object. The Employee object has a constructor which applies some checks to the parameters (for example, is it's ID > 0). We're using the code below to deserialize the JSON's. But is this constructor even called when deserializing the JSON to Employee?

Link to GSON: https://github.com/google/gson

**EDIT:**
So after experimenting with break points I figured out the constructor is not called. Does anybody know a way to get it called anyway?

```
/**
 * The GSON class to help you create and de-serialize the JSON objects.
 */
Gson gson = new Gson();

/**
 * Convert JSON to an object.
 * @param json The JSON to convert.
 * @param cls The class to convert to.
 * @return The converted JSON to object.
 */
public Object jsonToObject(String json, Class<?> cls) {
    return gson.fromJson(json, cls);
}
```

Comment: put a breakpoint in the constructor and debug the code, no?

Comment: @RC. Yes you're right, I just tested it and the constructor is not called.

Comment: I would assume it uses empty constructor to instantiate the object, and the read-in fields would be set using reflection directly.

Comment: Yes I figured that out. @EpicPandaForce

Comment: As I stated in my answer, you need to implement a custom `JsonDeserializer` and call a constructor from there. GSON does not support calling constructors, yet.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Libraries like GSON, Jackson or the Java Persistence API (JPA) generally use a no-argument (default) construtor to instantiate an object and set its fields via reflection. In newer versions of GSON, you do not even have to declare a default constructor anymore, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645050/is-default-no-args-constructor-mandatory-for-gson).

If you have to call a specific constructor in GSON, you can implement a custom `JsonDeserializer`, like already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187724/force-gson-to-use-specific-constructor).

In other libraries like Jackson, you can define the deserialization on methods, instead of fields (like GSON [does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203487/why-does-gson-use-fields-and-not-getters-setters)), which allows you to substitute the missing specialized constructor call.

Comment: `Jackson` has an annotation `@JsonCreator` that now lets you mark constructors to be used for serialization.