# Gson.fromJson not failing if some fields are not given even though marked as @NonNull

Tags: java, gson, lombok

I have a POJO defined as follows:

```
@Value
public class Abc {

    @NonNull
    private final String id;

    @NonNull
    private final Integer id2;

    @NonNull
    private final List<String> data;

    @NonNull
    private final String otherData;
}
```

When I am doing,

```
GSON.fromJson(str, Abc.class);
```

with str as:

```
{
"id": "dsada",
"id2": 12,
"data": ["dsadsa"]
}
```

In this, there is no otherData field. Even then, GSON.fromJson is not failing. Why is it so? Then, is there any significance of marking the field as @NonNull?

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626690/gson-optional-and-required-fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altgough with lombok `@Value` you get a allArgs constructor, Gson will not use it. Note that lombok will generate the allArg constructor for you so there will be no noArg constructor - but that will not be a problem for Gson (beggining from Gson 2.3.1 - check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645050/is-default-no-args-constructor-mandatory-for-gson)).

`@NonNull` annotation will make lombok generate null checks inside the constructor but this constructor will not be invoked. That is why Gson will read your Json without any problem.

Comment: Is there any way I can make Gson use this constructor?

Comment: check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187724/force-gson-to-use-specific-constructor)